# Adding content to Drupal database

Tags: 6, database, theming

I'm running a rather large Drupal 6 site and I need to include additional information in the database, things that run independently of Drupal. Is it best to create a separate database and connect to it from the files I need to access the info from, or is it just safe to add a custom table to the Drupal database and add whatever I want in there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, it's no problem to add tables to the database. It won't hurt Drupal. That said, I wouldn't recommend it. If things already *are* separated and there is no important reason to use a single db, just keep them separated for flexibility and performance in the future.

Comment: OK super, thanks, I'll keep the additional info in a separate db then...